# http to https htacces - redirected you too many times

Tags: .htaccess

I already have base url `www.example.com` and I want to have base url like this: `https://www.example.com`

This is in my httaccess file:

```
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

But when i access to my page with Chrome, its gives error:

```
The example.com Web has redirected you too many times.
```

After that code I have some other codes in `.htaccess` - maybe that cause problem?

```
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  -----
  </IfModule>
```

How to solve this error?

Comment: Perhaps you are behind a proxy server. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43743283/htaccess-rewrite-too-many-redirects

Comment: I try the code in that article, and its still dont work.